# Neo4j for storing pcap data

Tags: apache-kafka, neo4j, pcap

I'm a PhD student from VCU. I'm planning to use Neo4j to store network data in a power system (data from pcap). The power system consists of substation and data will be stored in roughly 1200 data points, at a 120hz rate.
I have a couple of questions.

1. What is the best way to store real-time data into Neo4j? Is it
   Kafka, or any other recommendations?
2. Can i do multiple data injection to Neo4j using community edition?
3. Can I run multiple Cypher queries simultaneously?
4. Is it a good idea to store high-speed
   network .pcap data into Neo4j?

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You might find this interesting in terms of pcap data, Kafka, and Neo4j: https://www.confluent.io/blog/stream-analyze-visualize-data-with-kafka-ksqldb-and-friends/

Answer (score 0):

Some of your questions are very general and are prone to opinionated answers.

1. The "best way" would depend on a variety of factors and who you ask. But since you specifically asked about using Kafka, you could take a look at the [Neo4j Streams](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/neo4j-streams/current/) plugin in neo4j 4.x.
2. It is not clear what "multiple data injection" means.
3. Yes.
4. Again, this is a matter of opinion and depends on a variety of considerations. It is not possible to give a general answer.

Comment: 1) I am wondering whether I can inject data into Neo4j in real time, without using Kafka? What is the advantage of using Kafka with Neo4j?                                                               2) If i have several subsystem/producers who access same database, can all producers inject data into the Neo4j?                                                                                3) let's say for example, I want to store DOS attack data (IP,time, port, flag) in Neo4j, will graph database will be a good option?